# Dúvida RMI e JNDI

Tags: java, rmi, jndi

Fala galera blza!,

atualmente comecei a estudar RMI (Remote Method Invocation) com JNDI (Java Naming and Directory Interface).

Sucintamente, pelo que aprendi até o momento é que o a tecnologia RMI é a responsável por permitir a invocação de métodos remotos (carregado em uma JVM remota) localizados no lado servidor. E o JNDI seria um auxiliador que ajuda o cliente a encontrar esses objetos.

Não achei na internet algum artigo que auxilie o ingresso do programador a essas tecnologias em conjunto (alguns descrevem o uso apenas do RMI e outros apenas do JNDI).

Gostaria de saber se alguém contem ou poderia me indicar algum material sobre o assunto, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns resources para você estudar. Mas já adianto que são um pouco antigos, já que o RMI também é uma tecnologia antiga e deixada um pouco de lado por novas tecnologias. Estão em inglês os materiais.

**[RMI Java](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565924525)**

**[RMI Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-rmi.html)**

**[Use JNDI to share objects between different virtual machines](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076440/jndi/use-jndi-to-share-objects-between-different-virtual-machines.html)**

**[JNDI overview, Part 1: An introduction to naming services](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076888/core-java/jndi-overview--part-1--an-introduction-to-naming-services.html)**

**[JNDI overview, Part 2: An introduction to directory services](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076901/jndi/jndi-overview--part-2--an-introduction-to-directory-services.html)**

**[JNDI overview, Part 3: Advanced JNDI](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076055/jndi/jndi-overview--part-3--advanced-jndi.html)**

**[JNDI overview, Part 4: the Doc-u-Matic, a JNDI application](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076074/core-java/jndi-overview--part-4--the-doc-u-matic--a-jndi-application.html)**

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado!, farei uso desses materiais.